# Doctrine querybuilder difference in initialisation?

Tags: doctrine-orm

I noticed that in tutorials there are different ways of instantiating the querybuilder.

```
1. $em->getRepository("Users")->createQueryBuilder('u')
2. $em->createQueryBuilder();
```

Is there a significant difference in using it with or without repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QueryBuilder in the repository will preset the `from` and `select` parts for you whereas the second one creates an empty QueryBuilder.